# Slice model category and initial/terminal objects

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories, slice-category

Consider $(M,Fib,Cof,WE)$ a model category, that is a complete/cocomplete category with 3 wide subcategories satisfying certain properties.
Now consider $X\in\operatorname{Ob}M$ and the slice category $M_{/X}$ (objects are triples $(m,*,f_m:m\to X)$). Consider $U_X:M_{/X}\to M$ the forgetful functor. I have shown that $(M_{/X},U_X^{-1}(Fib),U_X^{-1}(Cof),U_X^{-1}(WE))$ is a model category.

I have two questions : Is there always a (unique) terminal/intial object in a model category ?

Can we describe fibrant and cofibrant elements more than saying their images by the forgetful functor are fibrant or cofibrant ?

Comment: there are terminal/initial objects since they are the limit/colimit of the empty diagram and $M$ is complete/cocomplete

Comment: The first axiom of a model category is typically (co)completeness, so initial and terminal objects must exist.  They are always unique up to iso in any category, not just model categories.

Comment: What sort of description of (co)fibrant objects do you want?  Beyond what the definition explicitly says.

Comment: The object $A \to X$ in the slice model structure is cofibrant when $A$ is a cofibrant object in $M$, so it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: That's what I thought for initial/terminal thank you to both of you. Now for (co)fibrant objects it's just a question that asks to describe them in the slice category. I thought maybe there was something more than just saying that the component is (co)fibrant, for example the choice of $X$ but I guess not.

Comment: Randall is incorrect. An object in a (co)slice category is (co)fibrant if and only if the underlying morphism is a (co)fibration.

Comment: Am I that rusty [it's been 15 years]?  We need the map $(\varnothing \to X) \to (A \to X)$ to be a cofibration since $\varnothing \to X$ is the initial object in the slice category.  This reduces to needing the map $\varnothing \to A$ to be a cofibration in $M$, which means $A$ is cofibrant.  If this is wrong I'd like to have my reasoning corrected because now I'm worried about the state of my memory.

Comment: @ZhenLin Suppose we do the case of fibrations. Is a morphism from the terminal object to $(X,*,id_X)$ a fibration ? If yes I agree, if not I don't know how to prove your statement. I wanted to use the 2 out of 3 axiom to show the underlying morphism is a fibration one of the two remaining morphisms is maybe not a fibration.

Comment: A cofibrant object in the slice category is one where the domain is cofibrant – yes. But a fibrant object is a fibration. There is an asymmetry here!

Comment: @ZhenLin Then I don't see what I said above that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Zhen Lin in the comments we have an asymmetry here. Fibrant objects in the slice category are the objects with a structure morphism which is a fibration. This is not the case for cofibrant objects where we require the structure object to be cofibrant itself. In the coslice category however we would have that the fibrant objects are the ones who have a fibrant structure object, and cofibrant objects are the ones who have a cofibration as structure morphism.